# How to create an Instance of NSImage from the content of the screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage

I'm trying to capture an image from screen. Possibly with an input parameter like NSRect to specify which part of the screen that I want. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a top view (`NSScreenSaverWindowLevel` or higher) and save its bitmap data. Here's a sample code(not tested):

```
[topView lockFocus];
NSImage *screenRectShot = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize( screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height )];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:yourRect];
[screenRectShot addRepresentation:rep];
[rep release];
[topView unlockFocus];
```